# Recyclerview and notifiydatesetchanged doesn't show items until scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

Last week I faced a strange behavior and new issue with recycler view. Recyclerview doesn't show items until scrolling, actually, after debugging I knew that `onbindeViewHolder` didn't call after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

This is my adapter code:

```
class CalendarAdapter(val viewModel: CalendarViewModel) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var items: List<RequestBookingBaseModel>

    fun setData(data: List<RequestBookingBaseModel>) {
        items = data
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        if (::items.isInitialized) {
            return items.size
        }

        return 0
    }
}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

My activity is like this:

```
class CalendarFragment : BaseFragment() {
    ...
    do something
    ...

    fun showList(listOfItems : ArrayList<String>){
         var adapter = CalendarAdapter(viewModel)

         binding.dayPickerRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

         binding.dayPickerRecyclerView.layoutManager = getLayoutManager()

         adapter.setData(listOfItems)

    }
}
```

And, my activity layout is:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dayPickerRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"/>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think everything is ok with adapter and activity, But why items didn't show until scrolling recycler view up and down?

Answer (score 5):

After a day and removing all code whole around the application I found the solution. It was quite stupid. 
The problem was `ConstraintLayout` library.

I use the `ConstraintLayout` version `2.0.0-beta2` and the problem was just for this version, so I downgraded to version `2.0.0-beta1` and everything fixed, just it!! 
It took a day for me to fix.

May this be helpful and saves your time.

Just use

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Comment: Maybe you have found what was causing this issue to occur? I am in a similar situation, just I can not downgrade ConstraintLayout version due to MotionLayout usage...

Comment: what about upgrading? @TheScriptan

Comment: I found the fix. I had mixed topToBottomOf with bottomToTopOf values. For some reason in 1.1.3 XML worked fine, but in 2.0.0-betaX it did not.

Comment: This solved my issue alright. This was the most stupidest bug I had seen in constraint layout and wasted hours trying to debug what was wrong with my code. Turns out that trying the latest library didn't cross my mind.